# string comparison fails in a If condition with a string array element

Tags: c, arrays, string

In my code I have separate function to set string elements through a function to the `breakerOptions[]` array.`"time"` is one of the string stored in that array

```
char * breakerOptions[6];
......
int i=0;

while (i<6){
    breakerOptions[i]=(char *)malloc(10);
    strcpy(breakerOptions[i],FILE_BREAKER_OPTION_ARRAY[i]);
    i++;
}

if (breakerOptions[1]=="time"){
    printf("\nYeah first\n");
}
```

But the thing is that if condition's fails for no reason
Then I put a `printf` to check if it's stored.

```
printf("\nYeah first,%s %d\n",breakerOptions[1],(int)sizeof(breakerOptions[1]))
```

even thought its there it doesn't work.
I also checked the size of `breakerOptions[1]`. It gives me 8.

Comment: ah. 
`breakerOptions[1] = "15468";`
`if (breakerOptions[1]=="15468"){`
`printf("\nYeah first\n");`
`}`

but this works. ?